# Chrome extension event page persistent for certain pages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have an event page which sets up a fairly large connection to an `indexedDB`.

The extension uses this database quite often through message passing and I was wondering whether it would be best just to keep the background persistent for this page alone.

I was thinking maybe opening a port connection and not closing it, would this be a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to `IndexedDB` you can only have one connection to it at a time, meaning that if you intend of having other pages (frames) access it, leaving it open will not work. However, if you are using a messaging system, you could have all windows talk to the same point of access and therefore keep the connection open. It's not a bad idea if you plan on doing that, but keep in mind that if you allow for multiple instances of the application to run in parallel, then it might not be a good idea.

Comment: hm, some good things to think about. the only one who can open the `indexedDB` would be the background script therefore I wouldn't suspect there to be multiple instances.